# Codeigniter Generate Dynamic Table Row Data

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, dynamic, codeigniter-3

I am trying to load dynamic table data, my URI is;

```
example.coma/admin/view/form/<form_id>
```

My model query is;

```
public function getRecords($table, $form_id) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($table);
        $this->db->where('form_id', $form_id); 
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result_array(); 
        } 
}
```

This returns an array of data, I need to build a HTML table based on this array.

I'll show an example of two different arrays returned by the query.

**Array 1.**

(`select * from members where form_id = 123`)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 104
            [member_no] => 
            [firstname] => Peter
            [lastname] => Keys
            [address] => 17 main road
            [email] => P3TER@HOTMAIL.CO.UK
            [postcode] => UK123
            [city] => London
            [telnum] => 123123123
            [fk_form_submission_id] => 123
        )
)
```

**Array 2.**

(`select * from orders where form_id = 123`)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [colour] => blue 
            [type] => shirt
            [age] => 34
            [size] => medium
            [quantity] => 2
            [discount] => Y
            [posted] => N
        )
)
```

What I want to achieve is display a vertical table to display the dataset. Obviously each table will have different row names, example below;

**Table 1.**

```
+---------------+-------+
| ID            | 104   |
+---------------+-------+
| Member Number |       |
+---------------+-------+
| First Name    | Peter |
+---------------+-------+
| Last Name     | Keys  |
+---------------+-------+
| etc           | etc   |
+---------------+-------+
```

**Table 2.**

```
+--------+--------+
| Colour | blue   |
+--------+--------+
| P Type | shirt  |
+--------+--------+
| Age    | 34     |
+--------+--------+
| Size   | medium |
+--------+--------+
| etc    | etc    |
+--------+--------+
```

How can I set these table row names? Do I need to create another array of table headers and merge both arrays?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: you can do it by `foreach` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand - but if you want to set the keys of the array dynamiclly you can do that with `foreach` loop as:

```
<table>
<tr><th>Key</th><th>Value</th></tr>
<?php foreach($res[0] as $key => $val)
    echo '<tr><td>'. $key . '</td><td>' . $val . '</td></tr>'; ?>
</table>
```

**Edit:**

If you want to change the keys name to something more displayable I would recommend using another array for swap (most of the time it done for translation...).

```
$displayName = array("id" => "ID", "member_no" => "Member Number", "firstname" => "First Name" ..., "type" => "P type", ...);
foreach($res[0] as $key => $val)
    echo '<tr><td>'. $displayName[$key] . '</td><td>' . $val . '</td></tr>';
```

You can also use `array_combine` but that will need to know which kind of keys you have...

Notice that this solution will work only if the display name are unique for all kind of keys

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek - now I think I understand what was your issue - updated my post